# Is it possible to use media selector in styled-components to set attributes?

Tags: reactjs, media-queries, responsive, styled-components

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
const ResponsiveDiv = styled.div.attrs({
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        className: 'lg';
    }
})``;
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use media queries in styled components. You could create a wrapper component to wrap the responsive content.

```js
const ResponsiveDiv = styled.div`
  @media (max-width: 700px) {
    // your styles here
  }
`;
```

**Usage**

```js
render() {
  <ResponsiveDiv>
    // content goes here
  </ResponsiveDiv>
}
```

Refer [here](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#media-templates)

Comment: I see. I wanted to avoid putting identical components with different attributes, i.e. <ResponsiveDivSm dispalyItems="2" />,  <ResponsiveDivXs dispalyItems="5" />

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way with styled-components, but you kind of have a workaround with the [matchMedia](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_media_queries.asp) window property.

Here is my example:
I have an Component to display a pagination with a specific number of children depending of the screenWidth

```
<PaginatedElements
    renderChildren={renderImage}
    multipleChildren={3}
    elements={data} />
```

I want to change the `multipleChildren` props, depending of the `@media`.

I created a new component `ResponsivePaginatedElements`, using `window.matchMedia` which is a translation of css media queries to JS, to display the correct `PaginatedElements` according to the width :

```js
function    ResponsivePaginatedElements(props) {
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1200px)').matches)
        return (<PaginatedElements multipleChildren={3} {...props} />);
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 992px)').matches)
        return (<PaginatedElements multipleChildren={3} {...props} />);
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)').matches)
        return (<PaginatedElements multipleChildren={2} {...props} />);
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 576px)').matches)
        return (<PaginatedElements multipleChildren={1} {...props} />);
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 0px)').matches)
        return (<PaginatedElements multipleChildren={1} {...props} />);
}

<ResponsivePaginatedElements
    renderChildren={renderImage}
    elements={data} />
```